# R create vector with a for and while loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, vector, while-loop

Good morning,
I have the following problem.
My Data.frame "data" has the format:

```
Type    amount
1       2
2       0
3       3
```

I would like to create a vector with the format:

```
1
1
3
3
3
```

This means I would like to transform my data.
I created a vector and wrote the following code for my transformation in R:

vector <- numeric(5)

```
for (i in 1:3){
     k <- 1
     while (k <= data[i,2]){
         vector[k] <- data[i,1]
         k <- k+1
 }
 }
```

The problem is, I get the following results and I have no Idea at which part I go wrong…

```
3
3
3
0
0
```

There might be many different ways in solving this particular problem in R but I am curious why my solution doesn't work. I am thankful for alternatives, but really would like to know what my mistake is.
Thank's for your help!

Comment: If you are going to use a for/while solution you need to keep a separate index for the vector, now you are going to set `vector[1]` multiple times with different values.

Comment: may be `stack(unlist(apply(data, 1, function(x) rep(x['Type'], x['amount']))))`

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar  Just `with(data, rep(Type, amount))` will do, but I think the OP wants to do with `while/for` loop

Comment: @akrun OK I didn't see that

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar  Perhaps copy/pasting the source code of `rep` will be sufficient.

Comment: The proposed solution with(data…) works perfect for me. I still just wonder why my original attempt doesn't work. I do use a separate index by vector[k] or am I getting something wrong here. Thank's for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
df <- data.frame(type = c(1, 2, 3), amount = c(2, 0, 3))
result <- unlist(mapply(function(x, y) rep.int(x, y), df[, "type"], df[, "amount"]))
result
```

Output is following:

```
# [1] 1 1 3 3 3
```

Exaclty your code is buggy. Correct code should looks following:

```
df <- data.frame(type = c(1, 2, 3), amount = c(2, 0, 3))
vector <- numeric(5)
k <- 1
for (i in 1:3) {
    j <- 1
    while (j <= df[i, 2]) {
        vector[k] <- df[i, 1]
        k <- k + 1
        j <- j + 1
    }
}
vector
# [1] 1 1 3 3 3
```

Comment: Thank's for your input! Now I understand my error and got different versions to work with!

Answer (score 2):

Probably the fastest and most elegant way to obtain this result has been posted before in a comment by @akrun:

```
with(data, rep(Type, amount))
[1] 1 1 3 3 3
```

However, if you want to do this with for/while loops, it could be helpful to use a list for such cases, where the number of entries is not known at the beginning.

Here is an example with minimal modifications of your code:

```
my_list <- vector("list", 3)
for (i in 1:3) {
  k <- 1
  while (k <= data[i,2]){
    my_list[[i]][k] <- data[i,1]
    k <- k + 1
  }
}
vector <- unlist(my_list)
#> vector
#[1] 1 1 3 3 3
```

The reason why your code didn't work was essentially that you were trying to put too much information into a single variable, `k`. It cannot serve as both, an index of your output vector, and as a counter for the individual entries in the first column of `data`; a counter which is reset to `1` each time the `while` loop has finished.

Comment: Another wrapper is `expandRows(data, 'amount')` from `library(splitstackshape)`

Comment: Thank's a lot! This was the missing part of information! @akrun: Thank's for the simple way of solving this problem and your continuous input!

Comment: @akrun It's amazing how people sometimes give downvotes. Your solution was awesome.